# What is the meaning of ATS_STATIC_PREFIX?

Tags: ats

For instance, I saw the following line the other day:

```
#define ATS_STATIC_PREFIX "_Game_of_24_"
```

What is the meaning of such a line? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: 2nd result on a google search gives a clear answer...

Answer (score 1):

Its literally one search on the google.
[Here](http://discourse.ats-lang.org/t/ats-static-prefix/771) is the site.

Here is the quoted answer for your question:

> When the DATS-file is
>   compiled into C, the prefix 'foo__' is attached to  the original names
>   of static variables and functions in the generated C code.
>
> This feature can be very useful if one wants to mix the C code
>   generated  from multiple ATS source files as doing so is likely to
>   result in name conflicts among static  variables and functions in the
>   C code. Such conflicts can be resolved by properly setting 
>   ATS_STATIC_PREFIX. The same applies to loading PHP code generated from
>   ATS source.